# Convert np.nan to pd.NA

Tags: python, pandas, nan

How can I convert `np.nan` into the new `pd.NA` format, given the `pd.DataFrame` comprises `float`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['A', 'B'])
df.iloc[0, 1] = 1.5
df.iloc[3, 0] = 4.7

df = df.convert_dtypes()

type(df.iloc[0, 0])  # numpy.float64 - I'am expecting pd.NA
```

Making use of `pd.convert_dtypes()` doesn't seem to work when `df` comprises `float`. This conversion is however working fine when `df` contains `int`.

Comment: is `convert_dtypes` your own function?

Comment: @Erfan no, it's from pandas 1.0.0.

Comment: Thought I knew the pandas API by heart, but learned something new today, thanks for that

Comment: Seems like `convert_dtypes` has arguments to convert strings, integers and booleans with `pd.NA` support, but not floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From v1.2 this now works with floats by default and if you want integer use `convert_floating=False` parameter.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['A', 'B'])
df.iloc[0, 1] = 1.5
df.iloc[3, 0] = 4.7

df = df.convert_dtypes()
df.info()
```

output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   A       1 non-null      Float64
 1   B       1 non-null      Float64
dtypes: Float64(2)
memory usage: 104.0 bytes
```

Working with ints

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['A', 'B'])
df.iloc[0, 1] = 1
df.iloc[3, 0] = 4

df = df.convert_dtypes(convert_floating=False)
df.info()
```

output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       1 non-null      Int64
 1   B       1 non-null      Int64
dtypes: Int64(2)
memory usage: 104.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

Will fillna work for you?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['A', 'B'])
df.iloc[0, 1] = 1.5
df.iloc[3, 0] = 4.7

df = df.fillna(pd.NA)
```

df

```
      A     B
0  <NA>   1.5
1  <NA>  <NA>
2  <NA>  <NA>
3   4.7  <NA>
```

Look at type

```
type(df.iloc[0, 0])
```

Out:

```
pandas._libs.missing.NAType
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that your dataframe now has `object` dtype columns which makes them slow.

Comment: With this solution you get the correct `pd.NA` type. However, `df.info()` will now reveal that your columns changed from `float64` to `object`. That's not what I am looking for. The whole column should become `float64`.

Comment: @Andi looks like that functionality does not exist (yet?). You could raise an enhancement proposal issue at the pandas github repo.

Comment: Speed is a casualty of using pd.NA. This solution solves the question asked and thus should be marked as one, since the original question only wanted pd.NA to be used regardless of efficiency. Additionally, the original question did not specify additional datatype requirements.